# Custom Chat like Gmail or Skype in .Net Web Application

Tags: gmail, chat

We developing web app like Gmail. For this need Gmail or Skype like chat system. But we don't know is there any open source is available for this ?? or What are the methods we need to follow. IF any one having experience in this please add your suggestion to this post.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

GTalk use an open protocol called [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol)/[Jingle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jingle_%28protocol%29). If you want just instant messaging, XMPP should be enough, and you can find more information about it (for example, a [list of libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/)). If you want also to have voice call & all, you can use the [google library](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/), it's open source ([BSD License](http://opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause)).

Comment: Thank You Thagor. Is there any Open Source versions are available  ??

Comment: I added links in my answer. You can click on them to have a list of libraries XMPP (don't know if there is some open source, but I would think so), and the google open source project for the Jingle library.

Comment: Thank you. Can i use this in windows and .net platform ??

Comment: If i use Google Library  this included Text and voice chat ?? As you given Link for List of libraries if you can you please tell me which is most reliable.

Comment: The AG Software solutions seems nice in C#, you can found an all OS version [here](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/), and a Windows only using more advanced .NET features and Silverlight [here](http://www.ag-software.de/matrix-xmpp-sdk/).
The Google librarie is in C++, and you can find all the needed documentation in the link already given.

Comment: Thank You Thagor we started development with Openfire server and matrix sdk hope this will work for us.